# Find out which network interface adds a particular DNS search domain on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, domain

In my automatically generated `resolv.conf`, I have

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain1 domain2
```

I know that an OpenVPN connection pushed `nameserver 192.168.1.1` and `search domain1` to my local machine. Is there anyway to find out which network interface added `search domain2` to `resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `resolvconf` package has a directory (`/run/resolvconf/interface`) where the configuration associated with each interface are kept.  If it is interface related, the domain entry will be listed in one of those.  See the manpage (man resolvconf) for more documentation.

It is common to have default values as well. These are located in the `/etc/resolvconf` directory tree.

Comment: Thank you, @BillThor. This is exactly what I wanted to know. I can't find this information using `man resolvconf`

Comment: @Tanachat  Enter the command `man resolvconf` on the command line.  This will display the manual for resolvconf.

Comment: I meant that `man resolvconf` doesn't talk about `/run/resolvconf/interface`